# juntar dos registros en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar en mi problema. Necesito que esta tabla:

```
select a.ISSUEID,a.SHEETFORMID,a.PRESSRUNID,b.SIGNAME
from [PLANNER].[dbo].[prsseq_view] a, [PLANNER].[dbo].[sigs] b
where a.issueid = 41399 and a.SHEETFORMID='1' AND a.PRESSRUNID='1'
and  a.sigid=b.sigid and b.ISSUEID=41399
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me genere esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos siempre tendrán que tener en común el mismo **issueid** y el **signame**

Espero y me puedan ayudar gracias y saludos desde México ;)

---

edgar vazquez salio esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que faltaria en el codigo
saludos.

Comment: Hola podrias hacer uso de GROUP_CONCAT , me seria mas facil ayudarte si pondrias la consulta, pero ese GROUP_CONCAT  lo pondrias algo como GROUP_CONCAT (b.SIGNAME) y al final agrupar por los datos que mencionas que se repiten saludos

Comment: hola edgar la consulta es esta select a.ISSUEID,a.SHEETFORMID,a.PRESSRUNID,b.SIGNAME from [PLANNER].[dbo].[prsseq_view] a, [PLANNER].[dbo].[sigs] b
where a.issueid = 41399 and a.SHEETFORMID='1' AND a.PRESSRUNID='1' and a.sigid=b.sigid and b.ISSUEID=41399 y y los datos que se repiten o mas bien ahi que agrupar son los de signame como esta mencionado arriba

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto

Comment: ya esta saludos

Comment: De nada podrias marcar la respuesta como correcta si esa fue la que respondio tu pregunta saludos. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola prueba con esto y vemos lo que vaya saliendo

```
     SELECT a.ISSUEID,a.SHEETFORMID,a.PRESSRUNID,STUFF((SELECT ','+b2.SIGNAME FROM sigs b2 WHERE a.sigid=b2.sigid AND b2.ISSUEID=41399 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Resultado
 FROM prsseq_view a
 WHERE a.issueid = 41399 and a.SHEETFORMID=1 AND a.PRESSRUNID=1
 GROUP BY a.ISSUEID,a.SHEETFORMID,a.PRESSRUNID,a.sigid
```

saludos
Agrego imagen para observar el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui como lo hice puedes checarlo y si algo de los datos esta mal podemos verlo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1df77fc75fe83234547794aa0b9c4910

Comment: hola lo puse y me alojo este error:  Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Que error te mostros?

Comment: Es MYSQL tu base de datos no?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96665/discussion-on-answer-by-edgar-vazquez-juntar-dos-registros-en-sql).